# Filter array column in a dataframe based on a given input array --Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Dataframe like this

```
Studentname  Speciality
Alex         ["Physics","Math","biology"]
Sam          ["Economics","History","Math","Physics"]
Claire       ["Political science,Physics"]
```

I want to find all students who has speciality in [Physics,Math], so the output should have 2 rows Alex,Sam

This is what i have tried

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_contains
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def student_info():
     student_df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://studentdata")
     a1=["Physics","Math"]
     df=student_df
     for a in a1:
       df= student_df.filter(array_contains(student_df.Speciality, a))
       print(df.count())

student_info()

output:
3
2
```

Would like to know how to filter array column based on a given subset of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here another approach leveraging `array_sort` and the Spark equality operator which handles arrays as any other type with the prerequisite that they are sorted:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, array, array_sort, array_intersect

target_ar = ["Physics", "Math"]
search_ar = array_sort(array(*[lit(e) for e in target_ar]))

df.where(array_sort(array_intersect(df["Speciality"], search_ar)) == search_ar) \
  .show(10, False)

# +-----------+-----------------------------------+
# |Studentname|Speciality                         |
# +-----------+-----------------------------------+
# |Alex       |[Physics, Math, biology]           |
# |Sam        |[Economics, History, Math, Physics]|
# +-----------+-----------------------------------+
```

First we find the common elements with `array_intersect(df["Speciality"], search_ar)` then we use `==` to compare the sorted arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Using higher order function `filter` should be the most **scalable** and **efficient** way to do this ( **Spark2.4** )

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("new", F.size(F.expr("""filter(Speciality, x-> x=='Math' or x== 'Physics')""")))\
  .filter("new=2").drop("new").show(truncate=False)
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|Studentname|Speciality                         |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|Alex       |[Physics, Math, biology]           |
|Sam        |[Economics, History, Math, Physics]|
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
```

If you want to use an an `array` like `a1` to **dynamically** do this, you can use `F.array_except` and `F.array` and then `filter` on `size` ( **spark 2.4** ):

```
a1=['Math','Physics']
df.withColumn("array", F.array_except("Speciality",F.array(*(F.lit(x) for x in a1))))\
  .filter("size(array)= size(Speciality)-2").drop("array").show(truncate=False)

+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|Studentname|Speciality                         |
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
|Alex       |[Physics, Math, biology]           |
|Sam        |[Economics, History, Math, Physics]|
+-----------+-----------------------------------+
```

**To get count**, you could put `.count()` instead of `.show()`

Comment: So we have `transform` , also `filter` (TIL), nice one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have, no duplicates are in `Speciality` for a student (e.g.

```
StudentName   Speciality
SomeStudent   ['Physics', 'Math', 'Biology', 'Physics']
```

You can use `explode` with `groupby` in pandas

So, for your problem

```py
# df is above dataframe
# Lookup subjects
a1 = ['Physics', 'Math']

gdata = df.explode('Speciality').groupby(['Speciality']).size().to_frame('Count')

gdata.loc[a1, 'Count']

#             Count
# Speciality
# Physics         3
# Math            2
```

Comment: There can be duplicates in Speciality column